# Нужно вывести массив без изменений в C#.

Tags: массивы, c#

Ввожу массив ,а в выводе он мне выводит произведение элементов.(Не судите строго я новичок.)
Как вывести его без изменений в строчку?

```
Console.WriteLine("Вводим Вектор");
int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] vector = new int[k];
for(x = 0;x < k;x++) 
{   
    string buff = Console.ReadLine();
    vector[x] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());           
}
Console.WriteLine("Наш Вектор");
for(x = 0;x < k;x++) 
{
    Console.Write("{0}",vector[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы хотите написать вот это:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Вводим кол-во элементов вектора"); 
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Вводим Вектор"); 
        int[] vector = new int[k];
        for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
        {
            vector[x] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Наш Вектор");
        for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:N}\n",vector[x]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.Мне просто нужно найти произведение Вектора на Матрицу вот только я еще новичок в Шарпе вот и возникают вопросы.